# Is it possible to merge two association tables in Sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have four tables. They are Brands, departments, categories and product_details. The models are

Brand model

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details, :dependent=>:destroy
  searchable do
    integer :id
    text :name
  end
end
```

Deparment model

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details, :dependent=>:destroy
  searchable do
    integer :id
    text :name
  end  
end
```

Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_details, :dependent=>:destroy
  searchable do
    integer :id
    text :name   
  end
end
```

ProductDetail model

```
class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :brand do
      brand.name
    end
    integer :department_id
    integer :category_id
end
```

If user searches for department 1 first I have get all product details based on department id. The resultant table must contain brand name, category name and department name also. Is it possible to do it using sunspot solr? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a Document for each Product with Brand, Department, Category and Product details.
Then you're able to search for what you want, and receive the information you need.

Comment: Thank u @Rene. But how create that Document

Comment: You can use the DataImportHandler ([DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler))  to import you related data.